# QThread speeds up after terminating instead of terminating

Tags: python, asynchronous, audio, pyqt5, qthread

I am totally confused by the QThread behavior. My idea is to acquire some audio signal in a qthread, save it in a python `queue` object and with a `QTimer` I read the queue and plot it using `pyqtgraph`. It works, however, only at around 6-7 fps. However, when I use `.terminate()` to terminate the thread, the thread does actually NOT terminate, but rather speeds up to > 100 fps, exactly what I actually wanted.

My issues:

- why does the QThread not terminate/is aborted/closed...?
- what is `.terminate()` actually doing?
- what is slowing down the normal `thread.start()`?

On a side note, I know that I am not using a Signal/Slot for checking if it should still run or not, I just want to understand this strange behavior, and why the thread is not fast from the very beginning! Something is maybe blocking the proper function and is turned off (?!) by the `.terminate()` function...

My minimal working example (hope you guys have a soundcard/mic somewhere):

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QGridLayout, QPushButton
from PyQt5.QtCore import QThread, QTimer
import sounddevice as sd
import queue
import pyqtgraph as pg
import numpy as np
import time

class Record(QThread):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.q = queue.Queue()

    def callback(self, indata, frames, time, status):
        self.q.put(indata.copy())

    def run(self):
        with sd.InputStream(samplerate=48000, device=1, channels=2, callback=self.callback, blocksize=4096):
            print('Stream started...')
            while True:
                pass

        print(self.isRunning(), 'Done?') # never called

class Main(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.recording = False
        self.r = None
        self.x = 0
        self.times = list(range(10))

        self.setWindowTitle("Record Audio Tester")

        self.l = QGridLayout()
        self.setLayout(self.l)

        self.pl = pg.PlotWidget(autoRange=False)
        self.curve1 = self.pl.plot(np.zeros(8000))
        self.curve2 = self.pl.plot(np.zeros(8000)-1, pen=pg.mkPen("y"))

        self.l.addWidget(self.pl)

        self.button_record = QPushButton("Start recording")
        self.button_record.clicked.connect(self.record)
        self.l.addWidget(self.button_record)

    def record(self):
        if self.recording and self.r is not None:
            self.button_record.setText("Start recording")
            self.recording = False
            self.r.terminate()

        else:
            self.button_record.setText("Stop recording")
            self.recording = True

            self.r = Record()
            self.r.start()

            self.t = QTimer()
            self.t.timeout.connect(self.plotData)
            self.t.start(0)

    def plotData(self):
        self.times = self.times[1:]
        self.times.append(time.time())

        fps = 1 / (np.diff(np.array(self.times)).mean() + 1e-5)
        self.setWindowTitle("{:d} fps...".format(int(fps)))

        if self.r.q.empty():
            return

        d = self.r.q.get()

        self.curve1.setData(d[:, 0])
        self.curve2.setData(d[:, 1]-3)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication([])

    w = Main()
    w.show()

    app.exec_()
```

**edit 1**

The first suggestion @Dennis Jensen was to **not** subclass QThread, but use rather QObject/QThread/moveToThread. I did this, see code below, and one can see that the issue is gone with either using `while` and just `app.processEvents()` or `while` with `time.sleep(0.1)`, but to make it response you have to use anyway `app.processEvents()`, so this is sufficient. The `pass` statement alone eats up alot of CPU processing power, resulting in 7-10 fps, but if you `thread.terminate()` this thread, everything still runs.

I added additionally a trace, what happens on which thread, and the callback is always on a separate thread, regardless which callback you use (outside any class, in QObject or in the main thread), indicating that the answer from @three_pineapples is correct.

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QGridLayout, QPushButton, QCheckBox
from PyQt5.QtCore import QThread, QTimer, QObject, pyqtSignal, pyqtSlot
import threading
import sounddevice as sd
import queue
import pyqtgraph as pg
import numpy as np
import time

q = queue.Queue()

# It does not matter at all where the callback is,
# it is always on its own thread...
def callback(indata, frames, time, status):
        print("callback", threading.get_ident())
        # print()
        q.put(indata.copy())

class Record(QObject):
    start = pyqtSignal(str)
    stop = pyqtSignal()
    data = pyqtSignal(np.ndarray)

    def __init__(self, do_pass=False, use_terminate=False):
        super().__init__()
        self.q = queue.Queue()
        self.r = None
        self.do_pass = do_pass
        self.stop_while = False
        self.use_terminate = use_terminate
        print("QObject -> __init__", threading.get_ident())

    def callback(self, indata, frames, time, status):
        print("QObject -> callback", threading.get_ident())
        self.q.put(indata.copy())

    @pyqtSlot()
    def stopWhileLoop(self):
        self.stop_while = True

    @pyqtSlot()
    def run(self, m='sth'):
        print('QObject -> run', threading.get_ident())

        # Currently uses a callback outside this QObject
        with sd.InputStream(device=1, channels=2, callback=callback) as stream:
            # Test the while pass function
            if self.do_pass:
                while not self.stop_while:
                    if self.use_terminate: # see the effect of thread.terminate()...
                        pass # 7-10 fps
                    else:
                        app.processEvents() # makes it real time, and responsive

                print("Exited while..")
                stream.stop()

            else:
                while not self.stop_while:
                    app.processEvents() # makes it responsive to slots
                    time.sleep(.01) # makes it real time

                stream.stop()

        print('QObject -> run ended. Finally.')

class Main(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.recording = False
        self.r = None
        self.x = 0
        self.times = list(range(10))
        self.q = queue.Queue()

        self.setWindowTitle("Record Audio Tester")

        self.l = QGridLayout()
        self.setLayout(self.l)

        self.pl = pg.PlotWidget(autoRange=False)
        self.curve1 = self.pl.plot(np.zeros(8000))
        self.curve2 = self.pl.plot(np.zeros(8000)-1, pen=pg.mkPen("y"))

        self.l.addWidget(self.pl)

        self.button_record = QPushButton("Start recording")
        self.button_record.clicked.connect(self.record)
        self.l.addWidget(self.button_record)

        self.pass_or_sleep = QCheckBox("While True: pass")
        self.l.addWidget(self.pass_or_sleep)

        self.use_terminate = QCheckBox("Use QThread terminate")
        self.l.addWidget(self.use_terminate)

        print("Main thread", threading.get_ident())

    def streamData(self):
        self.r = sd.InputStream(device=1, channels=2, callback=self.callback)

    def record(self):
        if self.recording and self.r is not None:
            self.button_record.setText("Start recording")
            self.recording = False
            self.r.stop.emit()

            # And this is where the magic happens:
            if self.use_terminate.isChecked():
                self.thr.terminate()

        else:
            self.button_record.setText("Stop recording")
            self.recording = True

            self.t = QTimer()
            self.t.timeout.connect(self.plotData)
            self.t.start(0)

            self.thr = QThread()
            self.thr.start()

            self.r = Record(self.pass_or_sleep.isChecked(), self.use_terminate.isChecked())
            self.r.moveToThread(self.thr)
            self.r.stop.connect(self.r.stopWhileLoop)
            self.r.start.connect(self.r.run)
            self.r.start.emit('go!')

    def addData(self, data):
        # print('got data...')
        self.q.put(data)

    def callback(self, indata, frames, time, status):
        self.q.put(indata.copy())
        print("Main thread -> callback", threading.get_ident())


    def plotData(self):
        self.times = self.times[1:]
        self.times.append(time.time())

        fps = 1 / (np.diff(np.array(self.times)).mean() + 1e-5)
        self.setWindowTitle("{:d} fps...".format(int(fps)))

        if q.empty():
            return

        d = q.get()
        # print("got data ! ...")

        self.curve1.setData(d[:, 0])
        self.curve2.setData(d[:, 1]-1)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication([])

    w = Main()
    w.show()

    app.exec_()
```

**edit 2**

Here the code that uses no QThread environment, and this works as expected!

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QGridLayout, QPushButton, QCheckBox
from PyQt5.QtCore import QTimer
import threading
import sounddevice as sd
import queue
import pyqtgraph as pg
import numpy as np
import time


class Main(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.recording = False
        self.r = None
        self.x = 0
        self.times = list(range(10))
        self.q = queue.Queue()

        self.setWindowTitle("Record Audio Tester")

        self.l = QGridLayout()
        self.setLayout(self.l)

        self.pl = pg.PlotWidget(autoRange=False)
        self.curve1 = self.pl.plot(np.zeros(8000))
        self.curve2 = self.pl.plot(np.zeros(8000)-1, pen=pg.mkPen("y"))

        self.l.addWidget(self.pl)

        self.button_record = QPushButton("Start recording")
        self.button_record.clicked.connect(self.record)
        self.l.addWidget(self.button_record)

        print("Main thread", threading.get_ident())

    def streamData(self):
        self.r = sd.InputStream(device=1, channels=2, callback=self.callback)
        self.r.start()

    def record(self):
        if self.recording and self.r is not None:
            self.button_record.setText("Start recording")
            self.recording = False
            self.r.stop()

        else:
            self.button_record.setText("Stop recording")
            self.recording = True

            self.t = QTimer()
            self.t.timeout.connect(self.plotData)
            self.t.start(0)

            self.streamData()

    def callback(self, indata, frames, time, status):
        self.q.put(indata.copy())
        print("Main thread -> callback", threading.get_ident())


    def plotData(self):
        self.times = self.times[1:]
        self.times.append(time.time())

        fps = 1 / (np.diff(np.array(self.times)).mean() + 1e-5)
        self.setWindowTitle("{:d} fps...".format(int(fps)))

        if self.q.empty():
            return

        d = self.q.get()
        # print("got data ! ...")

        self.curve1.setData(d[:, 0])
        self.curve2.setData(d[:, 1]-1)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication([])

    w = Main()
    w.show()

    app.exec_()
```

Comment: anki be very carefully if anyone tells you to sub-class a QThread they are doing you a extreme disservice (or do not know squat about QThreads) as that has numerous little quirks and issues associated with and that is why it has not been the way to implement a QThread since Qt4 here is a link to how to do it right granted its in C++ but its fairly easy to port to PyQt  https://mayaposch.wordpress.com/2011/11/01/how-to-really-truly-use-qthreads-the-full-explanation/

Comment: I believe as @musicamante has pointed out below (and other than sub-classing QThread) you are going to have issues with that While Loop -- as soon as you reach that `while True:` endless loop your process will most likely lock up -- because python only effectively handles 1 Thread at a time in a linear fashion and the while loop is never going to hand back control to the Event Handler as you have it set up.  When streaming data be it numbers, audio, visual you have to be very careful about locking down your process -- however there are a few libraries that have been created to handle this

Comment: Thanks that was really helpful! Just for the record, subclassing QThread is definetly **wrong**, however, I couldn't see a difference in performance/behavior between QObject/QThread and using QThread directly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is due to the `while True: pass` line in your thread. To understand why, you need to understand how PortAudio (the library wrapped by sounddevice) works.

Anything passed a callback like you are doing with `InputStream` is likely calling the provided method from a separate thread (not the main thread or your `QThread`). Now from what I can tell, whether the callback is called from a separate thread or some sort of interrupt is platform dependent, but either way it is operating somewhat independently of your `QThread` even though the method exists inside that class.

The `while True: pass` is going to consume close to 100% of your CPU, limiting what any other thread can do. That is until you terminate it! Which frees up resources for whatever is actually calling the callback to work faster. While you might expect the audio capture to be killed along with your thread, chances are it hasn't been garbage collected yet (and garbage collection gets complicated when dealing with C/C++ wrapped libraries, nevermind when you have two of them! [PortAudio and Qt] - And there is a good chance that garbage collection in Python might not actually free the resources in your case anyway!)

So this explains why things get faster when you terminate the thread.

The solution is to change your loop to `while True: time.sleep(.1)` which will ensure it doesn't consume resources unnecessarily! You could also look into whether you actually need that thread at all (depending on how PortAudio works on your platform). If you move to the signal/slot architecture and do away with the `with` statement (managing the open/close of the resource in separate slots) that would also work as you wouldn't need the problematic loop at all.

Comment: This is actually the right solution. I update the question to give the right result based on both ways. Thank you so much!

Comment: @anki you're welcome! This is totally off topic but I checked out your profile and came across stytra! I've worked on something similar for physics experiments called the labscript suite (also with a focus on experiment replication). Really cool to see people in other fields doing similar things!

Comment: @anki and three_pineapples -- there are various libraries that allow the streaming of data (audio and/or visual) that function like one would think a thread would operate and this is only happening due to one of three reasons -- one this external program uses something other than python in its code base -- or two it instantiates a separate process to handle this --

Comment: or three it is using the `QCoreApplication.processEvents()` or something similar to allow other Threads to process their event queues from time to time -- I say this because threads within Python-PyQt are subject to Python's GIL which states that only one thread can be processed at a time. Just mentioning this so you a better understanding of what is actually going on as normal Threads in python will not work so cleanly without one of these 3 elements when you are doing something continuous like streaming

Comment: @DennisJensen what you have said is not completely correct (I'm very familiar with Python and PyQt threads). While only one Python thread will be active at a time due to the GIL, any Python code in a thread that is I/O bound will act in a responsive way. In the case of this question, the launched QThread was CPU bound due to the `while True: pass` statement, which effectively starved the other threads of computation time. Making it I/O bound either with a sleep call, or similar, fixes the problem, and has nothing to with how the AV library operates as ALL AV libraries are I/O bound by nature.

Answer (score 0):

There are some small issues in your code, all concurring to the "low" framerate, mostly due to the fact that you're using a blocksize of 4096 (which is too high if you want frequent updates) and are also trying to update the GUI too fast *while* also processing data.

On a slightly old computer as mine, your code completely hangs the interface as soon as I start recording, and stopping is almost impossible if not by killing the app at all.
What you see is not the thread "speeding" up, but rather the QTimer that has much more "time" (cycles) to call its timeout more frequently.

First of all, you shouldn't use `terminate`, but maybe use a Queue to send a "quit" command to the while loop, allowing it to exit gracefully.
Then, it's better to use signals/slots to retrieve and process the output data, as it's more intuitive and improves the overall cpu load.
Finally, if you want to get the fps of the received data, there's no use in a QTimer set to 0 (which will make it only run as fast as possible even if unnecessary, making the cpu spike needlessly).

```
class Record(QThread):
    audioData = pyqtSignal(object)
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.stopper = queue.Queue()

    def callback(self, indata, frames, time, status):
        self.audioData.emit(indata.copy())

    def run(self):
        with sd.InputStream(samplerate=48000, channels=2, callback=self.callback, blocksize=1024):
            print('Stream started...')
            while True:
                try:
                    if self.stopper.get(timeout=.1):
                        break
                except:
                    pass
        print(self.isRunning(), 'Done?') # never called

    def stop(self):
        self.stopper.put(True)


class Main(QWidget):
    # ...
    def record(self):
        if self.recording and self.r is not None:
            self.button_record.setText("Start recording")
            self.recording = False
            self.r.stop()

        else:
            self.button_record.setText("Stop recording")
            self.recording = True

            self.r = Record()
            self.r.audioData.connect(self.plotData)
            self.r.start()

    def plotData(self, data):
        self.curve1.setData(data[:, 0])
        self.curve2.setData(data[:, 1]-3)

        self.times = self.times[1:]
        self.times.append(time.time())

        fps = 1 / (np.diff(np.array(self.times)).mean() + 1e-5)
        self.setWindowTitle("{:d} fps...".format(int(fps)))
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. However, blocksize  is not limiting. The Qtimer is not limiting. Regarding the terminate, how can the Qtimer update more frequently when I killed the thread that is acquiring the data?! That makes no sense to me. As I wrote, my issue is that it works super fast as expected, when I click the button again and "terminate" the thread. With all suboptimal code.

Comment: @anki Unfortunately I cannot do more thorough tests right now, so I'll just try and give my opinion (which is more of a supposition, since it's not fact-checked). I *think* that what the callback actually does is to create a *reference* to the data array object while it's still being written by the audio buffer; so, the result is that the queue is *not* empty, but it cannot be fully processed by pyqtgraph until completion (the end of the buffer, based on the blocksize), hence "blocking" the refresh in the meantime. Have you tried to decrease the blocksize? Does the framerate improve?

Comment: @DennisJensen I'd have agreed with you until some time ago, but the situation is a bit more complicated, especially since Qt4.8/5, as it all depends on the interaction between worker and mainloop + thread affinity ( http://vikingsoftware.com/how-to-use-qthread-properly or http://woboq.com/blog/qthread-you-were-not-doing-so-wrong.html ). Moreover, Python's threading can add further issues. So, as a rule of thumb, QThread subclass is not always suggested [on PyQt] indeed, but I believe that's not the issue here. That said, have you even tried the moveToThread approach? The result is *the same*.

Comment: Not only have I tried and successfully used the MoveToThread in a fairly complicated endeavor of multiprocessing within many threads but I have helped several other programmers with issues surrounding the sub-classing QThread by helping them with implementing the MoveToThread methodology -- and it not only works but it magically gets rid of the issues these folks were having -- it is why I say sub-classing the QThread introduces quirks and these quirks are not all the same but the solution is always the same -- stop sub-classing the QThread and use it as it should be used

Comment: Okay so you have a couple of articles by a couple nice sounding guys but frankly that is not going to help the newer programmers with this because frankly they are not going to fully understand all that straight out of the box -- yes you can sub-class a QThread for very specific reasons but in general it is a very bad thing to do because you have to be extremely careful in how you implement that sub-classed QThread -- as such the general rule is -- do not use sub-classing QThreads as that is not the proper way to implement a QThread in 90% or more of the situations that are going to come up

Comment: @DennisJensen I was talking about *this* particular issue.

Comment: yep and this particular issue falls within the 90% of the time situation -- however if I am wrong on that please elaborate on how I am wrong

Comment: As replied to the OP, it seems that the problem is not directly related to the QThread subclass issue (for which I strongly agree with you about the moveToThread approach). As said, it seems that the `sounddevice` implementation of the `with` statement *might* not be very friendly with the Qt loop (no matter what thread approach is used). I've seen similar issues with other asynchronous processes resulting in unexpected behavior; also, video streaming is not the same as direct audio *processing*, as the timing of an (especially analog-sourced) audio device buffer is completely unreliable.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201436/discussion-between-dennis-jensen-and-musicamante).

Comment: @musicamante, thanks for looking into this! Actually it was the issue with the while True: pass command; only processing Events ameliorates everything quite well! Otherwise the Streaming happens in a separate thread, which we can now use directly to stream the audio data!